# How can I convince Netbeans to treat .phpclass files just like .php files?

Tags: php, netbeans, file-extension

I use Netbeans 7.3 (on Windows 7) at my job for PHP development. Some of the PHP classes are found in files named something like `MyClass.phpclass`. Apparently, Netbeans doesn't consider them to be actual PHP files, so all editor features are disabled: syntax highlighting, autocomplete etc.

Is there some way I can convince Netbeans that `.phpclass` files are just like `.php` files ? Obviously, renaming the files is out of the question because everyone uses the same code (100+ people).

I tried finding something about this in Tools -> Options -> Editor, but with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Tools -> Options -> Miscellaneous -> Files

-create a phpclass extension

-associate with mime text/php-5

-click OK

you're done!